When does the weak derivative of a function exist?
I've tried to find an answer but people use integrals or explain things with Sobolev spaces which I do not know how to use in this context and have not studied(not in my syllabus). I cannot understand from definition when a function has a weak derivative at a point. Does it exist when all the partial derivatives of it exist at this point and are equal? Or is it sufficient that the partial derivatives exists and their value is a finite number at this point of a function?
So what should I do when my task sounds like:

Inspect the differentiability of a function, f.e. $$f(x,y)= 
      \frac{sin(xy^3)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}},$$ $when (x;y) \neq (0;0) $
$$ f(x;y) = 0
 $$ $when (x;y) = (0;0) $

Check if weak and strong derivatives exist, and inspect the differentiability of a function when, f.e.:
$$f(x;y)=\sqrt{x^4 + y^4}$$
or
$$f(x;y) = \frac{x^3y^3}{x^4 + y^4}$$
$when (x;y) \ neq (0;0)$
$$f(x;y) = 0$$
$when (x;y) = (0;0)$


I just do not understand work of a theory behind those examples. Mostly, I do not understand when we can tell that a weak derivative of a function exists.
Appreciate all the answers.
